# How to alter HTML once an Ajax event is completed in WooCommerce

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce products listing page with products filter. Product filter works on Ajax. Ajax affects product listing — reload new list with new items. I need to add class to affected by Ajax items. I use jQuery "ajaxComplete" for that. But once Ajax event is completed, the selector class isn't added to the items.

It seems like jQuery do not "see" all HTML code generated by Ajax code. How can I get it?

PS: I can't make any changes in Ajax code because it's WordPress/WooCommerce code and I don't want to change it.

Here is a simplified code, just to get in:

```
<h1> My products </h1>
<!-- Ajax affect all items down this row -->
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="..."/>
        <div>Product name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="..."/>
        <div>Product name</div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
<!-- End of Ajax affect -->

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    jQuery(".item").addClass("size_2x1");   // apply Class. After product filters appling this class removes.
});

jQuery( document ).on( "ajaxComplete", function() {
    jQuery(".item").addClass("size_2x1");   //  do not works
    jQuery("h1").hide();                    //  works
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
$( "body" ).on( "ajaxComplete", ".item", function( event ) {
  jQuery(".item").addClass("size_2x1");
});
```

Or I use to work with WooCommerce AJAX Products Filter and in the plugin configuration, i have some fields to add JS on differents events like after before and after some action... Maybe that's the same thing in your case